# My component don't display and I don't have error

Tags: angular, components

Actually I following a tutorial about Angular on "Coursera" but I'm blocked at a step where I need to display a component but he doesn't work and I don't have error in my terminal.

[My terminal after npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwXZo.png)

***I looking for display the menu component (menu.component.html) :***

```
    <div class="container"
     fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <mat-list fxFlex>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
      <img matListAvatar src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
      <h1 matLine> {{dish.name}} </h1>
      <p matLine>
        <span> {{dish.description}} </span>
      </p>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

***menu.component.ts :***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes: Dish[] = [
  {
    id: '0',
    name: 'Uthappizza',
    image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    featured: true,
    label: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Zucchipakoda',
    image: '/assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    featured: false,
    label: '',
    price: '1.99',
    description: 'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Vadonut',
    image: '/assets/images/vadonut.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    featured: false,
    label: 'New',
    price: '1.99',
    description: 'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
    image: '/assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
    category: 'dessert',
    featured: false,
    label: '',
    price: '2.99',
    description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms'
  }
  ];

  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

}
```

***Dish.ts (in a shared folder) :***

```
export class Dish {    

    id!: string;
    name!: string;
    image!: string;
    category!: string;
    featured!: boolean;
    label!: string;
    price!: string;
    description!: string;
    
    }
```

***And the result :***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bixBW.png)

I know that I working with a deprecated version but I new in Angular and need your help for a better understanding of my problem.

I waiting your answers ...

Comment: I'm missing the parent component(s). Can it be that you also have an app.component? Please share that as well. First guess would be that you do not have <app-menu></app-menu> in your app.component.html

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I had added this element in my app.component.html but it didn't work before, or maybe I had the wrong file. Anyway, thank you, everything is working fine now !